# Powershell json format

Tags: json, rest, powershell

I have a question about convert from/to json with powershell. I need a json with a specific format (for a REST Call) but if I do an convertfrom-json and convertto-json the format is wrong and I don't know how I can change it. 
This is the original format:

```
{
    "property-content":  [
                             {
                                 "statKey":  "Test|Test1",
                                 "timestamps":  [1522678260000],
                                 "values":  ["compliant"],
                                 "others":  "",
                                 "otherAttributes":  ""
                             }
                         ]
}
```

and if I do an converfrom-json ... then I change some values and then I do an convertto-json the format is without the brackets:

```
{
    "property-content":  [
                             {
                                 "statKey":  "Test|Test1",
                                 "timestamps":  "1522678260000",
                                 "values":  "compliant",
                                 "others":  "",
                                 "otherAttributes":  ""
                             }
                         ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't do a lot of work with json, but I suspect that you need to force the new value to be an array before yoou change it in the json.

Comment: the square braces indicate the value is an array. if powershell doesn't interpret the input as an array then it won't output json text with the square braces. generally it doesn't matter, is your api complaining about it?

Comment: If you look a little deeper, you will notice that the single value array is not just changed to a value, but the value itself `."property-content"."timestamps"` type has also been cast from an `int64` to a `string`...

Answer (score 3):

The arrays are flattened by the [`ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) because of the `-Depth` parameter which is set to `2` by default. If you higher the `-Depth` it will resolve your issue:

```
PS C:\> $a = ConvertFrom-JSON @'
>> {
>>     "property-content":  [
>>                              {
>>                                  "statKey":  "Test|Test1",
>>                                  "timestamps":  [1522678260000],
>>                                  "values":  ["compliant"],
>>                                  "others":  "",
>>                                  "otherAttributes":  ""
>>                              }
>>                          ]
>> }
>> '@
PS C:\> $a | convertTo-JSON -Depth 5
{
    "property-content":  [
                             {
                                 "statKey":  "Test|Test1",
                                 "timestamps":  [
                                                    1522678260000
                                                ],
                                 "values":  [
                                                "compliant"
                                            ],
                                 "others":  "",
                                 "otherAttributes":  ""
                             }
                         ]
}
```